# How to change '.' emmet to expand as className instead of class when writing javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

like whenever I write `div.app` emmet expands it as `<div class="app"></div>` and I want this to stay true when extension of the file I'm writing is .HTML but in js, I want it to expand `<div className="app"></div>` to make it valid

Comment: what if you set it to use `javascriptreact` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration

Comment: Ahh I see, I use to put `html` on that place earlier that's why it gave me class instead of className. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to settings on VS Code, search for "includeLanguages". Add an object as `{"javascript": "javascriptreact"}` emmet will expand your code as `<div **className**="hello".../>` instead of `<div **class**="hello".../>`